# Flutter Firebase create a dynamic list of streams

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, stream-builder

How i can create a dynamic list of stream?

I need a function that build a stream list and return the stream.

My fuction (try to return a value like this `List<Stream<'dynamic'>>`:

```
List<Stream<dynamic>> _buildStreamList() async* {
  var chat_overview_object = await query_chat_overview_id();

  List<Stream<dynamic>> stream_list = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < chat_overview_object.length; i++) {
    stream_list.add(
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('chat')
          .doc('chat_overview_data')
          .collection('data')
          .doc('chat_overview_id_1234')
          .snapshots(),
    
    );
    
  }
  
yield stream_list;
}
```

Why i need this?

I try to build a streambuilder with multiple stream on documents.

The streams can be different (for example one stream look at collection a document a other on collection b document b).

The example work but only with fix streams. Now i would like implement a **function which return a dynamic list of streams.

Here my code:

```
var _data = [];

typedef MultiStreamWidgetBuilder<T> = Widget Function(BuildContext context);

// A widget that basically re-calls its builder whenever any of the streams
// has an event.
class MultiStreamBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const MultiStreamBuilder({
    required this.streams,
    required this.builder,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Stream<dynamic>> streams;
  final MultiStreamWidgetBuilder builder;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) => builder(context);

  @override
  State<MultiStreamBuilder> createState() => _MultiStreamBuilderState();
}

class _MultiStreamBuilderState extends State<MultiStreamBuilder> {
  final List<StreamSubscription<dynamic>> _subscriptions = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _subscribe();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(MultiStreamBuilder oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (oldWidget.streams != widget.streams) {
      // Unsubscribe from all the removed streams and subscribe to all the added ones.
      // Just unsubscribe all and then resubscribe. In theory we could only
      // unsubscribe from the removed streams and subscribe from the added streams
      // but then we'd have to keep the set of streams we're subscribed to too.
      // This should happen infrequently enough that I don't think it matters.
      _unsubscribe();
      _subscribe();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => widget.build(context);

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _unsubscribe();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _subscribe() {
    for (final s in widget.streams) {
      final subscription = s.listen(
        (dynamic data) {
          setState(() {
            _data.add(data);
            print('data: ' + _data.toString());
          });
        },
        onError: (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
          setState(() {});
        },
        onDone: () {
          setState(() {});
        },
      );
      _subscriptions.add(subscription);
    }
  }

  void _unsubscribe() {
    for (final s in _subscriptions) {
      s.cancel();
    }
    _subscriptions.clear();
  }
}

class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiStreamBuilder(
      streams: _buildStreamList(),
       [
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('chat')
            .doc('chat_overview_data')
            .collection('data')
            .doc('chat_overview_id_1233')
            .snapshots(),
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('chat')
            .doc('chat_overview_data')
            .collection('data')
            .doc('chat_overview_id_1234')
            .snapshots(),
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('chat')
            .doc('chat_overview_data')
            .collection('data')
            .doc('chat_overview_id_1232')
            .snapshots()
      ],
      builder: _buildMain,
    );
  }
}

Widget _buildMain(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
      home: Row(
    children: [
      Text(
        '_data: ' + _data.toString(),
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
      )
    ],
  ));
}
```

**Edit!**
After a while i got a solution:

```
//multi stream widget builder
typedef MultiStreamWidgetBuilder<T> = Widget Function(BuildContext context);

// widget that basically re-calls its builder whenever any of the streams has an event.
class MultiStreamBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const MultiStreamBuilder({
    required this.streams,
    required this.builder,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Stream<dynamic>> streams;
  final MultiStreamWidgetBuilder builder;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) => builder(context);

  @override
  State<MultiStreamBuilder> createState() => _MultiStreamBuilderState();
}

//multi streambuilder
class _MultiStreamBuilderState extends State<MultiStreamBuilder> {
  final List<StreamSubscription<dynamic>> _subscriptions = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _subscribe();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(MultiStreamBuilder oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (oldWidget.streams != widget.streams) {
      // Unsubscribe from all the removed streams and subscribe to all the added ones.
      // Just unsubscribe all and then resubscribe. In theory we could only
      // unsubscribe from the removed streams and subscribe from the added streams
      // but then we'd have to keep the set of streams we're subscribed to too.
      // This should happen infrequently enough that I don't think it matters.
      _unsubscribe();
      _subscribe();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => widget.build(context);

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _unsubscribe();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _subscribe() {
    for (final s in widget.streams) {
      final subscription = s.listen(
        (dynamic data) {
          setState(() {
            //check object contain id
            var object = chat_overview_object.singleWhere(
                (element) => element.chat_overview_id[0].trim() == data.id);

            //add to object data
            object.last_message_send = data['last_message_send'];
            object.last_update = data['last_update'];
            object.members_id = data['members_id'];
            object.new_message = data['new_message'];
            object.user_display_name = data['user_display_name'];
          });

          //set index
          index++;

          //check all data load
          if (index == chat_overview_object.length) {
            //set data has load
            data_load.value = false;
          }
        },
        onError: (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
          setState(() {});
        },
        onDone: () {
          setState(() {});
        },
      );
      _subscriptions.add(subscription);
    }
  }

  void _unsubscribe() {
    for (final s in _subscriptions) {
      s.cancel();
    }
    _subscriptions.clear();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong approach: You should not  build a separate `stream` for each `document`, then decide on which `stream` you are using. Instead, you should build only 1 `stream` that returns all those `documents` you may need.

Then, inside your `StreamBuilder`, you can apply your `if` condition to decide which `document` you need to use. This way, the document will always be up-to-date.

Make sure you apply the right `where` clause to call the appropriate `documents` from the database.

**EDIT 1:**

So what you need is known as a collectionGroup:

```
db.collectionGroup('data').where('yourField', isEqualTo: 'whatever').snapshots()
```

Comment: Hello @Canada, thx for your answer. My problem is, that i need multitpe documents to show my data. I build a chat room overview. For that i need different document becaus every data for one chat room are store in one document. If i would like show multitpe chat rooms i need multitpe documents. First i use a Futurebuilder but i would change data in real time. That the reason because i try to build a multitpe streambuilder.

Comment: You know that 1 stream gives you **multiple documents**, right?

Comment: Yeahh, but my stream in different collection. For example: User a write in three chat rooms. Each chat room data are contain in chat_room_1, chat_room_2 and chat_room_3.
Now i would like build a listview wich contains all chat rooms. To do that i need all collection. My problem is that also other user has her chat room data in this collection. It's heavy to explain. If you have question feel free to ask me.

Comment: I understand now... Did you consider using CollectionGroups: it is a new feature added in Firestore to get documents from multiple collections [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59172718/14728030)

Comment: No, thx for the idea. I will try it (:

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect what you really need

Comment: Hi @Canada, thx for your answer. I try to implement the collectionGroup example. The problem i found out that the user have not permission to do a collectionGroup. I'm using firebase and i set secure rules. For example i check in every document is user id contain. I need this to only allow only user in chat room read the data. Now after a while i have found a solution. Post it below.